# matlab code: Gaussian blurring in fourier domain

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, convolution

I am looking at some code which performs blurring of images. However, I am having trouble understanding the code and I was wondering if someone could help me understand what the code is doing roughly.

Here the variable "Iref" is an image.

```
Imin = min(Iref(:));

Iref_fft = Iref-Imin;
Iref_fft = fftshift(Iref_fft,1);
Iref_fft = fftshift(Iref_fft,2);

Iref_fft = fft(Iref_fft,[],1);
Iref_fft = fft(Iref_fft,[],2);

Iref_fft = fftshift(Iref_fft,1);
Iref_fft = fftshift(Iref_fft,2);
```

Here, I am already confused as to what it means to apply the fftshift on an image which is not already in the fourier domain. So, I can tell it is doing a fourier transform along each of the axes but why does it do a fftshift before and after?

The code follows as:

```
Nx_r = 32;
Ny_r = 32;
sigma = 1.5;
wx      = reshape(gausswin(Nx_r,sigma), [1 Nx_r]);
wy      = reshape(gausswin(Ny_r,sigma), [Ny_r 1]);
wx_rep  = repmat(wx, [Ny_r 1]);
wy_rep  = repmat(wy, [1 Nx_r]);
Window  = wx_rep .* wy_rep;

xIndices = floor((Nx-Nx_r)/2)+1 : floor((Nx-Nx_r)/2)+Nx_r;
yIndices = floor((Ny-Ny_r)/2)+1 : floor((Ny-Ny_r)/2)+Ny_r;

Iref_blurred = zeros(Ny,Nx);
Iref_blurred(yIndices,xIndices,:) = Iref_fft(yIndices,xIndices) .* Window;
Iref_blurred = fftshift( ifft2( fftshift(Iref_blurred) ) );
Iref_blurred = abs(Iref_blurred)+Imin;
```

In the subsequent steps, I think we are doing a Gaussian blurring. However, I thought the kernel has to be generated in the fourier domain as well before we could multiply them like the line:

```
Iref_blurred(yIndices,xIndices,:) = Iref_fft(yIndices,xIndices) .* Window;
```

I am not sure if the Window is the fourier transform of the Gaussian convolution kernel or at least not being able to tell it from the code.

So, I am a bit confused as to how this is achieving the Gaussian blurring. Any help in understanding this code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that there is no FFT of the Gaussian going on in this code, but the thing to remember (or learn) is that `the Fourier space representation of a Gaussian is also a Gaussian`, just with the reciprocal standard deviation.  Whoever wrote this code probably knew this, or they just forgot and got lucky.

See the section of `gausswin` docs called [Gaussian Window and the Fourier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/gausswin.html#btn0euv-1) Transform. Condensed version of `gausswin` example in documentation:

```
N = 64; n = -(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2; alpha = 8;
w = gausswin(N,alpha);
nfft = 4*N; freq = -pi:2*pi/nfft:pi-pi/nfft;
wdft = fftshift(fft(w,nfft));
plot(n,w)
hold on
plot(freq/pi,abs(wdft) / 10,'r')
title('Gaussian Window and FFT')
legend({'win = gausswin(64,8)','0.1 * abs(FFT(win))'})
```

[image]

So, interpreting the output of `gausswin` as the Fourier space right away, without performing and FFT, equates to a Gaussian window in the with a much larger sigma in the spacial domain.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! So, a very quick question. Say the standard deviation of my Gaussian kernel in the spatial domain is 2, then the SD of the fourier transformed kernel is 0.5?

Comment: @Luca I think it's proportional to the standard deviation.  Perhaps check online or in on math.stackexchange.com or dsp.stackexchange.com for the math details.